# Ionic Cloud: Getting Error Registry returned 404 for Get

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cloud

I keep getting this error in my output when trying to package iOS through Ionic cloud "Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/[MyAppName]". I've followed a few other forum posts that I could find to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using [MyAppName] as a placeholder for my physical app name; for the post. The issue turned out to be the Cordova plugins directory. 
To resolve I ran:

```
ionic state clear --plugins
```

This, however, resulted in only partial removal of the plugins. I further had to manually delete the rest. Finally I ran:

```
ionic state restore --plugins
```

I can build successfully now.

Comment: You should state clearly that it this will delete all cordova plugins and that the restore will not restore them.

Answer (score 0):

in `package.json` you have [MyAppName] as package or something like that, which when trying to fetch from npmjs.com its not there since you havent publish it, post `package.json` to check it.